# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException in Simple.oData.Client

Tags: c#, xamarin, odata

I have the following code to get oData with using `Simple.oData.Client`.It works. when I get wifi via my cell phone; however, when I connect via the company ethernet which is proxy protected, it gives me the following error. 
How could I handle it?

```
async partial  void Click_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
        {
            var client= new ODataClient("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/");

            Console.WriteLine("before await");

            try {
            var packages = await client
                .For("Customers").
                FindEntriesAsync();
                foreach (var package in packages)
                 {
                  //Console.WriteLine(package["CompanyName"]);
                  Console.WriteLine(package);
                 }
                }
                catch(AggregateException e) {
                   Console.WriteLine(e);
                   Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("after await");
       }
```

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred --->
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred --->
>   Simple.OData.Client.WebRequestException: Unexpected WebException
>   encountered ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure
>   (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:
>   Connection refused   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect
>   (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000f1] in
>   ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.8.2.4/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket_2_1.cs:1257
>   at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest
>   request) [0x001c2] in
>   ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.8.2.4/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:213
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
async partial  void Click_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
        {

            ODataClientSettings settings = new ODataClientSettings();

            NetworkCredential proxyNC = new NetworkCredential("Username", "password");

            settings.OnApplyClientHandler= (System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler clientHandler) => {

                clientHandler.Proxy = new WebProxy("yourproxy.com",false,null, proxyNC);
                clientHandler.UseProxy = true;
            };
            settings.UrlBase = "http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/";
            var client= new ODataClient(settings);

            Console.WriteLine("before await");

            try {
            var packages = await client
                .For("Customers").
                FindEntriesAsync();
                foreach (var package in packages)
                 {
                  //Console.WriteLine(package["CompanyName"]);
                  Console.WriteLine(package["CompanyName"]);
                 }
                }
                catch(AggregateException e) {
                   Console.WriteLine(e);
                   Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("after await");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the endpoint you are trying to connect to, is not listening for connections.

Comment: Yes, that is what error message says. How could I cope with?

Comment: You need to talk to your company's IT department about why they are blocking that site.  I don't think there is anything you can do about it in code

Comment: @Jason, it is very generic service, microsoft northwind data service.

Comment: if it works over your cell connection, but not over your corporate network, then it seems reasonable to assume IT is either blocking it, or their proxy is interfering with the connection somehow.

Comment: @Jason and feroze, I have posted the solution just in case you are interested and could give me any feedback for further improvement

Comment: Yeah, your solution is correct. By adding the proxy, you are having the HTTP request succeed. I should have read your original question more carefully :(